# :not(:empty):before pseudo-classes / elements combination

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I would like to display a label only if the content is there.

This does not work:
https://jsfiddle.net/9g0amsh1/

```css
.views-field-field-documents .field-content:not(:empty):before {
  content: "Documents associés : ";
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="views-field views-field-field-documents"><div class="field-content">
</div></div>
    
<div class="views-field views-field-field-documents"><div class="field-content">
    <span class="file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf"><a href="/system/files/article/documents/boarding-pass.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=117264">boarding-pass.pdf</a></span>
</div></div>
```

Comment: whitespace also counts.

Answer (score 1):

indeed whitespace counts.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2mLh9tz/

```
<div class="views-field views-field-field-documents"><div class="field-content"></div></div>

<div class="views-field views-field-field-documents"><div class="field-content"><span class="file file--mime-application-pdf file--application-pdf"><a href="http://dud-dev.univ-amu.fr/system/files/article/documents/boarding-pass.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=117264">boarding-pass.pdf</a></span>
</div></div>
```